# Easy to configure deny all except proxy?

Tags: proxy

I'm trying to setup a proxy in a very small enterprise setting (< 10 employees)

I'm looking for something that allows me to:

- refuse requests by default ...
- ... unless in the exception list (eg only allow some domains)
- logs all url, who asked for it, and whether it was accepted or denied (I don't need content)
- Is based on client/server and not "same machine", yet is fairly easy to setup (which is where I'm having issues, I find stuff that do everything but seem overly complex to configure, or simple stuff that are made to use on the computer doing the requests)

I don't need cache
I don't need path filtering (simple ip/domain will do)
I don't need authentification (every user will have the same permissions, log by source ip is enough)

What would you recommend for that ?

Comment: [Requests for product recommendations are considered off-topic](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) here and on nearly all Stack Exchange Q&A platforms with the exception of https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: You said you dont need content or filtering, but you want to log URL's.  This would require doing MITM decryption of sites.  You can default deny everything and do **[MITM](https://serverfault.com/questions/1051701/how-to-block-mime-types-by-https-with-squid/1051717#1051717)** with the open source Squid.  There are many examples on serverfault on setting ACL's in Squid.